# Postgresql в Ubuntu

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как удалить базу Postgresql и все что с ней связано (модули для django, суперпользователи) в Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю, лучше все пакеты удалить через synaptic.
база postgresql скорее всего находится в */usr/local/pgsql/data*
+можно воспользоваться командой locate

Answer (score 0):

Все данные django хранятся как таблицы в БД. Поэтому для удаления Вам достаточно просто удалить эту БД.
Вы можете сделать это, зайдя за суперпользователя БД (по-умолчанию, это пользователь postgres) и удалить ее через psql:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
# DROP DATABASE your_db_name;
```

Если Вы имеете в виду именно модули django - они устанавливаются через pip или easy install и могут быть удалены соответственно:
[Вот документация](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/)

Comment: Если имеется в виду удаление PostgreSQL как такового (а не только базы данных), то можно воспользоваться apt-get-ом: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation